# почему не работает namespace? php

Tags: php

```
 //Page.php
    namespace Models;
    
    class Page {
        public static function get($name) {
            echo 'hello ' . $name;
        }
    }
  
//PageController.php  
    namespace Controller;
    
    use \Models\Page;
    
    class PageController {
        public static function get() {
            Page::get('Misha');
            
        }
    }
    
    PageController::get();//Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Models\Page' not found in /var/www/html/nameSpace/Controller/PageController.php on line 19
```

Comment: все работает https://onlinegdb.com/JEOy6X1Lq

Comment: та то же в разных файлах должно быть

Comment: ну так подключай их правильно

Comment: а что пространство имен не подключает?

Comment: нет.  недостаточно просто написать пространство имён. пыха не знает ничего про прасположение файлов на физ. носителе, поэтому нужно инклудить файлы.... почитай про spl_autoload или composer